# imageView loses image after capturing photo in another imageVIew

Tags: android

I have two imageViews for capturing photos.

```
mImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE1);
                            }
    });




    mImageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE2);

        }
    });
```

And the activity result below:

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try {

        if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            bitmap1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");



            SharedPreferences myPrefrence = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefrence.edit();
            editor.putString("image1", encodeToBase64(bitmap1));
            editor.commit();


            String imageS = myPrefrence.getString("image1", encodeToBase64(bitmap1));
             decodedBitmap1 = decodeToBase64(imageS);

            Uri imageUri1 = bitmapToUriConverter(decodedBitmap1);
            imgRotation1 = getRotation(this, imageUri1);
            mImageView1.setRotation(imgRotation1);

            //COMPRESS
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            decodedBitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);

            mImageView1.setImageBitmap(decodedBitmap1);


            mImageView1.setSaveEnabled(true);
            mImageView1.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            bitmap2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");



            SharedPreferences myPrefrence = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefrence.edit();
            editor.putString("image2", encodeToBase64(bitmap2));
            editor.commit();


            String imageS = myPrefrence.getString("image2", encodeToBase64(bitmap2));
            decodedBitmap2 = decodeToBase64(imageS);



            Uri imageUri2 = bitmapToUriConverter(decodedBitmap2);
            imgRotation2 = getRotation(this, imageUri2);
            mImageView2.setRotation(imgRotation2);

            //COMPRESS
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            decodedBitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);

            mImageView2.setImageBitmap(decodedBitmap2);


            mImageView2.setSaveEnabled(true);
            mImageView2.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

I capture an image with the mImageView1 and show in it always with no problem. But when i capture an image with the mImageView2,  the mImageView1 sometimes (not always) loses the image. I have tried SharedPreferences to save the images and also compressing the images before i put them in the imageviews, but with no result. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution by myself.

i set to imageViews uris not bitmaps

for example

`mImageView1.setImageURI(imageUri1);`